# ¿Por qué me da un error al implementar un IntersticialAd?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo una app en la que quiero mostrar un anuncio del tipo intersticial. Anteriormente ya implemente banners con lo que dice su documentación, pero a la hora de hacer lo que dice la documentación peor para un intersticial me da un error, parece que no reconoce los métodos a ocupar; ya que me "aconseja" renombrarlos o crearlos.

El código es el siguiente:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        //Error aqui
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        //Error aqui
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        //Error aqui
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Y lo mando llamar en:

```
//Error aqui
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        //Error aqui
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
```

Reiterando que el error esta señalado por un comentario.
NOTA: Me pareció ver una pregunta similar, pero esta estaba en Kotlin, y desconozco ese lenguaje. Por ende no sabría aplicarlo o transformarlo.

Comment: Hola, puedes proporcionar un link a la documentación que leiste? Lamentable estaba desactualizada. [Esta](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) es la documentación actual

Comment: Es esa misma mi buen, de ahi estoy sacando todo (Incluido lo del banner)

Comment: Ah lo siento, parece que la nueva documentación no está disponible en español. Selecciona el idioma ingles y verás los ejemplos actualizados.

Comment: Es verdad, hay algo diferente; la revisare y veré si funciona

Answer (score 0):

En la [documentaciòn](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) indica que ahora debes inicializar pero posteriormente cargarlo usando un `AdRequest` pero implementando `InterstitialAdLoadCallback` para obtener los callback `onAdLoaded` y `onAdFailedToLoad`:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
      });

      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

      InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
        // an ad is loaded.
        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
      }

      @Override
      public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
        // Handle the error
        Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
        mInterstitialAd = null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Veo que la documentaciòn en español es incorrecta.